# How to store Array of tuples/arrays in snowflake and flatten to join another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm new to snowflake and trying to solve the below.

1. how to insert/store array of tuples in a column. Tried using array_construct( array_construct(...), array_construct(...) ). But this didn't work. Tuple will have fixed columns

```
Array < (recon_id1 ,file_id1, file_line_num1 ), (recon_id1 ,file_id2, file_line_num1)  >
```

2. Flatten the array and join the tuple with other table

```
from nested_array_table a 
join target_table t
on a.recon_id = t.recon_id
and a.file_id = a.file_id
and a.file_line_num = t.file_line_num
```

Could you please help me how to achieve this in snowflake.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Array could store another array and be unnested using `FLATTEN`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(col ARRAY) AS 
SELECT [[1,'a', 10], [2, 'b', 20], [3, 'c', 30]];

-- main query
SELECT sub.value[0]::INT, sub.value[1]::TEXT, sub.value[2]::INT
FROM tab
,LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT=>tab.col) sub;
```

Output:

```
SUB.VALUE[0]::INT   SUB.VALUE[1]::TEXT  SUB.VALUE[2]::INT
1   a   10
2   b   20
3   c   30
```

Answer (score 0):

so more to Lukasz's point about array construction if you just write a array in the square brackets form it is implicitly a call to [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct)

Thus while:

```
SELECT ['this', 'is','an','explicit','array'];
```

works

[image]

you cannot place that into a VALUES block

```
select * from values 
    (['this', 'is','an','explicit','array']);
```

[image: Invalid expression [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'an', 'explicit', 'array')] in VALUES clause]

which also means the for of INSERT into a table must be the SELECT form, as Lukazs noted not the other VALUES form,

```
insert into this_has_array(the_array) values 
    (['this', 'is','an','explicit','array']);
```

> Invalid expression [ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('this', 'is', 'an', 'explicit', 'array')] in VALUES clause

So you originally said you tried using nested ARRAY_CONSTRUCT and here is how to make it work (the SELECT form)

```
select array_construct(array_construct(1,2,3), array_construct(4,5,6)) as an_array;
```

[image]

### But WHY?

The reason the explicit or implicit ARRAY_CONSTRUCT does not work in the VALUES block is that VALUES requires explicit/constant values, and ARRAY_CONSTRUCT is a dynamic function, so although the input to the function is constant, it is not known at compile time of the SQL, it is a runtime value.

now if you have giant chunks of data you want to inject into the array/table you can use a string in the array_block, and cast to ARRAY via a PARSE_JSON:

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON(column1) as an_array
fROM VALUES
('[[1,"a", 10], [2, "b", 20], [3, "c", 30]]'),
('[[1,"d", 10], [2, "e", 20], [3, "f", 30]]'),
('[[1,"g", 10], [2, "h", 20], [3, "i", 30]]')
;
```

[image]

this still requires the SELECT form of insert, but does allow larger volumes of data to be inserted. But large volumes of data should avoid explicit INSERT forms and use files, at which point you might want to use this "strings" pattern to bring in the array as text and turn it into ARRAY as part of the file loading process.